# Check if additional hour due to DST

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, dst, java-time

In my application I must often check if given hour as `ZonedDateTime` is the additional hour due to DST. Consider the transition from **Summer time** to **Winter time**

```
1) *date* 01:00:00+02:00  
2) *date* 02:00:00+02:00
3) *date* 02:00:00+01:00
4) *date* 03:00:00+01:00
```

I want to write the simplest possible function `isExtraHour(ZonedDate time)` that for 1,2,4 will return `false` and for 3 case will return `true` Of course using the Java8 Time API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would use:

```
public boolean isExtraHour(final ZonedDateTime time) {
  return time.getZone().getRules().getValidOffsets(time.toLocalDateTime()).size() > 1;
}
```

Note that it returns true for the whole hour of overlap, which I assume is the answer you need.

Comment: In fact we use `ZonedDateTime` rather as timestamps with full hours, but I like your answer more than mine ;) Thx!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest I got so far is:

```
public boolean isExtraHour(final ZonedDateTime time) {
    final ZoneOffsetTransition dayTransition = time.getZone().getRules()
            .getTransition(time.toLocalDateTime());

    return dayTransition != null && dayTransition.isOverlap() && dayTransition.getInstant()
            .equals(time.toInstant());
}
```